# Pass function reference to custom node constructor via @NamedArg

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Here is my custom node:

```
public final class CustomNode {

    public CustomNode(@NamedArg("onStart") EventHandler<ActionEvent> startMethod) {
        //code
    }

}
```

And here is how I create it in my FXML file:

```
<CustomNode onStart="#start"/>
```

That doesn't work.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot determine type for property.
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.getSetterMethod(BeanAdapter.java:177)
    at javafx.fxml/com.sun.javafx.fxml.BeanAdapter.put(BeanAdapter.java:250)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:626)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:778)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2838)
    at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2557)
```

IMPORTANT:

I don't want to do this via properties (aka setOnStart and getOnStart methods inside CustomNode).
It has to be via NamedArg

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure this could be done in a way that's worth using. Possibly you could write a class implementing `EventHandler<ActionEvent>` that took an object and a method name as parameters, and implemented the `handle` method using reflection. Then do something like `<CustomNode><onStart><ReflectiveEventHandler object="${controller}" methodName="start" /></onStart></CustomNode>`. But that's ugly enough not to want to use, and I'm not sure it'd work without testing...

Comment: @James_D Thank you for your reply, but I also think it's ugly. It's such a shame that there's no documentation about NamedArg and I think JavaFX is messy. In that case, I'll just set my node some fx:id and add onStart manually in the controller's initialize method